# $R^2$ for mixed models = ICC?

Tags: mixed-model, model-selection, multilevel-analysis, intraclass-correlation

I will be referring here to [Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract). As those authors state, $R^2$ for OLS regression could be defined as follows:

$$R^2 = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(\bar{y} - \hat{y_i})^2}{\sum^n_{i=1}(y_i - \bar{y})^2} = \frac{var(\hat{y_i})}{var(\hat{y_i})}$$

and so, if we define mixed model like this:

$$y_{ij} = \beta_0 + \sum^p_{h=1}\beta_hx_{hij} + \alpha_{j} + \epsilon_{ij}$$

then $R^2$ could be defined as follows:

**$R^2$ for fixed effects ($R^2_m$)**:

$$R^2_m = \frac{\sigma^2_f}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

where:

$$\sigma^2_f = var\left( \sum^p_{h=1}\beta_hx_{hij}\right)$$

**$R^2$ for random effects ($R^2_c$)**:

$$R^2_m = \frac{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha}{\sigma^2_f + \sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

However, this seems to be the same as ICC:

$$ICC = \frac{\sigma^2_\alpha}{\sigma^2_\alpha + \sigma^2_\epsilon}$$

and so:

$$R^2_c - R^2_m \approx ICC$$

This puzzled me a bit. Could you correct me if I am wrong? Why ICC is the same as $R^2$ for mixed models? If those two measures are equivalent, why are they not used like this? (or if they are, could you provide a reference?) Could you explain why they are equivalent?

Reference:
Nakagawa, S. & Schielzeth, H. (2013). A general and simple method for obtaining
$R^2$ from generalized linear mixed-effects models. *Methods in Ecology and
Evolution, 4*, 133–142.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nakagawa and Schielzeth (2013) call $R^2$ as "closely connected to $R^2$" and refer to their 2010 paper. From posting this question I already seen few mentions of $ICC$ treated as "variance explained" since it in fact is a part of total variance explained by all the random effects and residuals. So it seems $ICC$ is used as an analog to $R^2$ while one have to remember that both statistics have their flaws (e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13314/is-r2-useful-or-dangerous) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125601/acceptable-values-for-the-intraclass-correlation-coefficient-empty-model/125606#125606)).

---

Nakagawa, S. & Schielzeth, H. (2010). [Repeatability for Gaussian and non-Gaussian
data: a practical guide for biologists](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-185X.2010.00141.x/abstract;jsessionid=981ED493E0B354FACBFFFC310EE04B55.f03t04). *Biological Reviews, 85*, 935–956.