# What does intracluster correlation mean?

Tags: sampling, cluster-sample

I am studying the topic of cluster sampling. I have learnt that intracluster correlation ($\rho$) measures the correlation over all clusters between distinct elements in the same cluster. I do not quite understand what this means. Can someone explain please and give an example if possible?

Answer (score 1):

In general ICC tells you about the

> "degree of similarity in the responses of individuals from the same
>   cluster for the outcome" ([Eldridge, Ukoumunne and Carlin, 2009](http://blizard.qmul.ac.uk/images/PCTU_files/Eldridge_et_at_ICC_in_CRTs.pdf))

and it

> describes how strongly units in the same group resemble each other ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intraclass_correlation))

So it tells you if the clusters are made of similar individuals versus being a random mixture of individuals. However this measure [could be misleading](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125601/acceptable-values-for-the-intraclass-correlation-coefficient-empty-model/125606#125606) and you should not take it at a face value.